# Autosys time condition

Tags: autosys

I have job A that have time condition as 6:00 and predecessor as job B(this completes mostly by 4:00). Yesterday job B did not ran and today after job B completion job A started as time condition was satisfied on previous day itself. I want to know whether is  there any way to make this time condition to be unsatisfied after that particular day completion so that there wont be any issues in next day?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using R11 version, then you can use lookback condition(refer CA manual for details)

syntax is
**status(job_name, hhhh.mm)**

eg
**condition: success(job_b,12.00)**

If job_b has become success in last 12 hrs, then condition is satisfied, else its not and the job_a doesnt run.

Hope this will do.